# Setting sdk.dir for Android in Teamcity

Tags: android, ant, teamcity

I've this configuration in Teamcity on Windows:

- Android Project
- Android SDK is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
- I'm using Ant to build the project

In Ant step I want to set SDK.DIR using the additional ANT parameters but the path with a space is getting me problems.

I've tried:

-Dsdk.dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

-Dsdk.dir=C://Program Files (x86)//Android//android-sdk

-Dsdk.dir="C://Program Files (x86)//Android//android-sdk"

-Dsdk.dir=%env.ANDROID_HOME%

and I get always the same error:

Cannot find C:\Program\tools\ant\build.xml

As a workaround I'm using the short path name:

-Dsdk.dir=C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk

Is it the only way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`-Dsdk.dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"` should work.  as well as

`-Dsdk.dir=%ANDROID_HOME%` (assuming the variable is set correctly).

Comment: No same problem. Seems to work only with the short name.